# Browser returns an error when I click Select

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Sometimes there is such an error in Chrome (sometimes it is and sometimes it is not)

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index.
    at chrome-extension://ogdfpjfkomoeoodbemmkloabcjkmmbol/contentScript.bundle.js:51:124433
    at HTMLDocument.w (chrome-extension://ogdfpjfkomoeoodbemmkloabcjkmmbol/contentScript.bundle.js:51:124680)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="categories">Kategoria</label> <select name="categoryId" id="categoriesss" class="form-control" onchange="changeCategory(this.value)">
    <select name="categoryId" id="categoriesss" class="form-control" onChange="changeCategory(this.value)">
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
      {
        <option value="@Html.Raw(Model.Categories[i].CategoryId)">@Html.Raw(Model.Categories[i].Name)</option>
      }
    </select>
  </select>
</div>
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Sounds like some browser extension is messing things up. (This one? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/underline/ogdfpjfkomoeoodbemmkloabcjkmmbol)

Comment: @CBroe Yes. I turned it off and it's ok now. Thank you very much